# Chronologically organize Cells in TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, sorting, twitter, nsarray

I have two `UITableViewCell`'s that each correspond to a `Twitter Tweet` or a `Instagram Pic`. As of now I have set it so that It will alternate between the two cells and have It go from an `Twitter Tweet` to an `Instagram Pic`. However I want to organize the `UITableView` so that it organizes both the `Twitter Tweets` and `Instagram Pics` chronologically in the TableView. Both the date keys for the Instagram API and the Twitter API are different. The Twitter API has a time key of `created_at` and Instagram's key is `created_time`. How would I organize both these Arrays? P.S. Both the arrays which the Tweets and Pics are in are `NSMutableArray`'s.

Here is the Code that I have tried thus far:

```
    // Setup for Cells
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        UITableViewCell *twitterCell = [self createTwitterCell:indexPath];
        UITableViewCell *instagramCell = [self createInstagramCell:indexPath];

        if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
            return twitterCell;
        }else{
            return instagramCell;
        }

    }

   // Array Updater
    - (void)updateArrays {
        instaPics = self.timelineResponse[@"data"];
        totalFeed = [tweets arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:instaPics];
        [self sortArrayBasedOndate:totalFeed];

    }

   // Current flawed method to organize by date
    - (void)sortArrayBasedOndate {
        NSDateFormatter *fmtDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [fmtDate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

        NSDateFormatter *fmtTime = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [fmtTime setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

        NSComparator compareDates = ^(id string1, id string2)
        {
            // Instagram Date Retrieval
            NSDictionary *instagram = self.instaPics;
            NSString *createdAt = instagram[@"created_time"];
            int createdAtN = [createdAt intValue];
            NSTimeInterval timestamp = (NSTimeInterval)createdAtN;
            NSDate *date1 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestamp];

            // Twitter Date Retrieval
            NSDictionary *twitter = self.tweets;
            NSDate *date2 = twitter[@"created_at"];

            return [date1 compare:date2];
        };

        NSSortDescriptor * sortDesc1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"start_date" ascending:YES comparator:compareDates];
        [totalFeed sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDesc1]];

    }
```

If you guys need any more code excerpts feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're on the right track. Why don't you also format Twitter's time to match your formatting for Instagram's time?

```
NSComparator compareDates = ^(id string1, id string2)
    {
        // Instagram Date Retrieval
        NSDictionary *instagram = self.instaPics;
        NSString *createdAt = instagram[@"created_time"];
        int createdAtN = [createdAt intValue];
        NSTimeInterval timestamp = (NSTimeInterval)createdAtN;
        NSDate *date1 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestamp];

        // Twitter Date Retrieval
        NSDictionary *twitter = self.tweets;
        NSString *twitterCreated = twitter[@"created_at"];
        int createdAtTwitter = [twitterCreated intValue];
        NSTimeInterval timestampTwitter = (NSTimeInterval)createdAtTwitter;
        NSDate *date2 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestampTwitter];

        return [date1 compare:date2];
    };
```

Comment: Well thanks but how would I display the Tweets/Pics in the UITableView? Instead of just doing this                      
      if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
            return twitterCell;
        }else{
            return instagramCell;
        }